# C# HttpWebRequest wait for result

Tags: c#, redirect, webrequest

I made an Application, which should download a file from the Internet. The Website where i want to download the file has a timer (something about 5 seconds) and i want to download this file from this Website: [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/redirect.php?product=CrystalDiskInfo). I already implemented a function to redirect to the normal site.

I am using this to get the new link:

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myString);
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
myString = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse().ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: All you're doing is loading the HTML. That's it. `HttpWebRequest` is not a browser.

Comment: I see. How to get the new Link when waiting for the file? I didnt find any solution for that

Comment: Well, normally those kinds of sites use JavasSript. It would entirely depend on the site if you can mimic what their JavaScript does. Otherwise you might want to look into running the page within a browser control in your application, or perhaps browser automation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.